# mesibo.js not setting up database stores correctly

Tags: mesibo

we're implementing Mesibo in our web application and one of the developers in our team encountered a problem with running app successfully in his browser (up-to-date Chrome running on MacOS).

He gets this error in logs:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on
> 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
> mesibo.js:83

When I checked his indexedDB in the browser I saw that "messages" and "contacts" stores were not set up (and they should be upon sdk initialization). Deleting "mesibo" database and running app again resulted in the same error. However, when running in incognito mode everything was fine and stores were correctly set up.

We are currently in the testing stage but I'd like to be sure that this problem will not show up to our users in production so I wonder if anyone here encountered such a problem and what could be a cause?

Comment: most likely that your indexDB is corrupted due to the browser crash. Try using a different name and see if that works

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I managed to solve the problem.
I was clearing mesibo db objects "messages" and "contacts" on logout. But when user didn't have mesibo database yet my transaction to indexedDB was creating new empty "mesibo" database. So after logout when user opened messages section the SDK was getting already existing "mesibo" db but without store objects and crashed. To solve issue I had to check if mesibo db already existed before clearing stores and if not - abort transaction to not create empty database.